# Android: Modifying contacts phone numbers using the existing phone numbers

Tags: android, contacts

I need to edit the phone numbers of contacts by using the existing phone numbers. I'm using the following code that doesn't work. My problem is with reading the existing phone numbers and making up the new phone numbers. How can I read the phone numbers before I update them?
Thanks in advance

```
 ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
                  new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

         ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                  .withSelection(String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER) + " Like ?", new String[]{String.valueOf("004-"+"%")})
                 .withValue(String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER), "008-"+String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
                  .build());
                    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

Comment: Are you having trouble fetching the contacts or updating them? There is a HUGE amount of information already out there. Here is an entire working example: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/provider/android-contacts-example/

Comment: @castling: Searching didn't hep me. I have trouble fetching the exact phone number that is being updated. For example, I want to change the beginning of all numbers that start with 004- and replace it with 008 (i.e. 004-677111 to 008-677111), so while updating I'm going to need what comes after 004- to append it after 008-. In the code, the line starting with .withvalue is for assigning the value and I have trouble with the second parameter. I don't know how to fetch the phone number of the contact which is being updated.